# Protractor - how to set chrome://flags/ when running tests

Tags: angular, google-chrome, protractor, angular-cli

My integration tests would benefit from a flag set in `chrome://flags` - specifically #enable-asm-webassembly. When the tests run they don't use my own user preferences so the flag is unset. Is there any way to set these?

Comment: use chromeOptions, localState to turn the flag on / off. The flag values are stored in a plain text file under AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State in Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

```
 capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            'args': ['start-minimized', 'window-size=1920,1080'],
            'localState': {
                "browser": {
                    "enabled_labs_experiments": ["enable-asm-webassembly@1"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can understand the dictionary structure by changing the flags and see how it is getting reflected in LocalState file.
The configuration is stored by Chrome under `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State`